# i show this error Conversion failed when converting datetime from character string

Tags: datetime

I want to save the number of fields in the Data Grid View, and then stored in the Database.

```
Private Sub btnSave_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnSave.Click
    Dim sql As String
    For i As Integer = 0 To dgvContract.Rows.Count - 1
        sql = "INSERT INTO ContractDetails(Customer_ID , Customer_Name , Contract_ID , Contract_Name ,Strat_Date , End_Date , Value , Description) VALUES(" & (dgvContract.Item("dgvCustomerID", i).Value) & ",'" & (dgvContract.Item("dgvCustomerName", i).Value) & "','" & (dgvContract.Item("dgvContractID", i).Value) & "','" & (dgvContract.Item("dgvContractName", i).Value) & "','" & Format(dgvContract.Item("dgvStratingDate", i).Value, "mm/dd/yyyy") & "','" & Format(dgvContract.Item("dgvEndDate", i).Value, " mm/dd / yy") & "','" & (dgvContract.Item("dgvValue", i).Value & "','" & (dgvContract.Item("dgvDescription", i).Value)) & "')"

        SqlHelper.ExecuteScalar(My.Settings.conn, CommandType.Text, sql)
    Next

End Sub
```

It shows me this error:

> Conversion failed when converting datetime from character string.

Comment: Make sure you format code correctly as code, and also tag what language that code is.

Comment: To 4 hours to see the code ..

Comment: What does "To 4 hours to see the code" mean? Since you are new, did you [Take the Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read about [How to Ask a Good Question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: There is this error I could not find a solution, unfortunately, because the English language is not strong

Comment: Right now, the code you have in your question is not readable, and you are missing a relevant language tag (`VB.Net`?). To make the question *better*, you should check the formatting of the code and make sure that your code and question are clear (making it more likely to get an answer).